# Flash Player on Android Emulator

Tags: android, flash

I need to test my Android app for playing flash objects in the WebView.

At first I didn't need to test it on the emulator since I have an actual device (Android 2.3.7) but since users have been reporting issues about the app on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich), I want to test it now in the emulator.

First I tried to install the Android Market using

```
adb install androidmarket.apk
```

After installing it, it just closes when I open it so I downloaded the Flash Player apk and installed it the same way.

```
adb install flashplayer.apk
```

So I tried the app but still no flash is playing.
Then I read somewhere that I should be installing the Adobe AIR instead. I installed the apk using the same approach

```
adb install adobeair.apk
```

Tried the app again but still the same. Just the blue box with a question mark appears.

Any idea how to test Flash videos on the Android emulator?

EDIT:
I've also tried

```
adb -e install -r adobeair.apk
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First I tried to install the Android Market

The Android Market/Google Play client is not licensed for distribution and use this way. You cannot obtain a legal download of this APK from Google.

> so I downloaded the Flash Player apk

Please point to where you can get an authorized download of this APK from an official Adobe Web site.

> Then I read somewhere that I should be installing the Adobe AIR instead. I installed the apk using the same approach

Please point to where you can get an authorized download of this APK from an official Adobe Web site.

> Any idea how to test Flash videos on the Android emulator?

Even *if* there were legal downloads of the required APKs (and I am not aware that there are), Flash/AIR depend heavily on hardware acceleration and cannot work in today's emulator.

Comment: I got the Flash Player apk here:
http://androidadvices.com/download-latest-adobe-flash-player-111-apk-android-phones-tablets/

and the Adobe AIR here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=6571754

Like you said, I guess this is going to be impossible (for now).

Answer (score 0):

Just a several days before, on the site:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/

You could have found many APK packages with various versions of FlashPlayer for Android. They even have been successfully installing on the emulator - although I actually DONT KNOW if they work properly (I had no point in running anything..).

As of today (=2012.11.18) they site is almost down, but you can still downlaod the packages, for example:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.115.27/install_flash_player_ics.apk

edit: I've just found the proper site:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

edit2: nope, it installs but does not seem to work. I've just tested http://www.adobe.com/swf/software/flash/about/flashAbout_info_small.swf on emulator and empty black page showed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the APK you need for all flash versions for Android 2.x and 3.x, even for Android 4.0 at the following location:
[Archived Flash Player versions](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#flash_player_archives)
Just scroll down a little bit